# Rowwise operation within for loop using dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, rowwise

I have some transport data which I would like to perform a rowwise if comparison within a for loop. The data looks something like this.

```
# Using the iris dataset 
> iris <- as.data.frame(iris)
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Where the result would record the instances of sepal lengths with equal petal width in each species. Such that we record the pairs of sepal lengths with equal petal width (this is only an illustration having no scientific significance). Which would yield something like this:

```
Species Petal.Width Sepal.Length1 Sepal.Length2
setosa          0.2         5.1             4.9
setosa          0.2         5.1             4.7
setosa          0.2         4.9             4.7
setosa          0.2         5.1             4.6
...
```

My initial Python-ish thought was to perform a for loop within a for loop, looking something like this:

```
for s in unique(Species):
  for i in 1:nrow(iris):
    for j in 1:nrow(iris):
      if iris$Petal.Width[i,] == iris$Petal.Width[j,]:
        Output$Species = iris$Species[i,]
        Output$Petal.Width = iris$Petal.Width[i,]
        Output$Sepal.Length1= iris$Sepal.Length[i,]
        Output$Sepal.Length2= iris$Sepal.Length[j,]
    end
  end
end
```

I had thought about using `group_by` to classify `Species` first to achieve the first for loop `for s in unique(Species):`. But I don't know how to rowwise compare each observation in the dataset, and to store it like the second block of code. I have seen questions on [for loops in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280462/how-to-write-loops-for-loops-in-r-using-dplyr-syntax) and [rowwise quantities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480362/dplyr-for-rowwise-quantiles). My apologies if the code above is not as clear. First time asking a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)    

iris %>%
      group_by(Species,Petal.Width) %>%
      mutate(n = n()) %>%
      filter(n > 1) %>%
      mutate(Sepal.Length1 = Sepal.Length,
             Sepal.Length2 = Sepal.Length1 - Petal.Width) %>%
      arrange(Petal.Width) %>%
      select(Species, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length1, Sepal.Length2)
```

This is grouping `Species` and `Petal.Width`, counting instances where they are the same, only selecting cases where there are more than 1 unique pairing, and then renaming `Sepal.Length` to `Sepal.Length1`, and creating a new variable `Sepal.Length2` = `Sepal.Length1` - `Petal.Width`

For recording `Sepal.Length` for each `Species` within a defined range:

```
minpw <- min(Petal.Width)
maxpw <- max(Petal.Width)

iris %>%
  group_by(Sepal.Length, Species, petal_width_range = cut(Petal.Width, breaks = seq(minpw,maxpw,by=0.2))) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the answer! What if I would like instead of pairs of equal `Petal.Width`, I would apply a range (say 0.2). So now pairs with `Petal.Width` of 0.2 and 0.4; or 0.4 and 0.6 would also satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Maybe just because it's late on Friday, but I'm having trouble following. You want to group `Petal.Width` that falls within a specified range of an absolute difference of 0.2? That would mean that a `Petal.Width` of .4 would satisfy both conditions, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. My apologies for not making it clearer. So in a sense, I want to find pairs with similar `Petal.Width` (a range of 0.2 here) in each `Species` and record their `Sepal.Length`.

Comment: I updated the post with an attempt, but not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I get what you are doing here and technically it does answer my question, but it's not what I was looking for. Would you please look at the revised question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421335/rowwise-operation-with-adaptive-range-using-dplyr